# Error updating 1 to many navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

excuses-me but I really need help.

I need to update an entity which has a collection of another entity (1-to-Many relation in Db) but when I try to do an update the main entity I end up having this error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'CustomProperties' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I'm using the project template "Aspnetboilerplate" and using their function to update entity.

Here is my "main" class / entity called "Mockup" :

```
public class Mockup : FullAuditedEntity<int, User>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Json { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public string Support { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomProperty> CustomProperties { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update the "CustomProperties" collection here above.

And here is my Customproperty class / entity :

```
public class CustomProperty : FullAuditedEntity<int>
{
    public int JsonElementId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public CustomPropertyType Type { get; set; }

    public Mockup Mockup { get; set; }
}
```

As i'm trying to do an update, I can't really understand why it's trying to do an "IDENTITY_INSERT" and how to do in another way. How can I make my update properly working ?

Here is an exemple of Json that I post to the aspnetboilerplate update function. It is mapped by Automapper to the entity posted above :

```
{
    "name":"okok",
    "json":"",
    "width":827,
    "height":1170,
    "support":null,
    "format":null,
    "customProperties":[
    {
    "jsonElementId":949264,
    "value":"150",
    "type":0,
    "id":3335
    },
    {
    "jsonElementId":427781,
    "value":"150",
    "type":0,
    "id":3336
    },
    {
    "jsonElementId":165189,
    "value":"366.99445670195036",
    "type":0,
    "id":3337
    },
    {
    "jsonElementId":110359,
    "value":"150",
    "type":0,
    "id":3338
    },
    {
    "jsonElementId":342044,
    "value":"150",
    "type":0,
    "id":3339
    }
    ],
    "id":8040
    }
}
```

When I do it for a new entity, it is creating in Db the Mockup entity and the CustomProperties too without any problem but When I try to update the collection (after deleting some CustomProperties in Collection) I have the error.

Comment: Post the code where you're trying to insert/update

Comment: @TheOne Ok I posted example below :)

Comment: The section below is for answers, please edit your question and include all the additional information

Comment: Ok it's Done @TheOne

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the default method AsyncCrudAppService. If you look to the 
update method : 
        `public virtual async Task Update(TUpdateInput input)
        {
            CheckUpdatePermission();

```
        var entity = await GetEntityByIdAsync(input.Id);

        MapToEntity(input, entity);
        await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

        return MapToEntityDto(entity);
    }`
```

The entity is loaded without any includes, so Entity framework is trying to insert the elements contained in your navigation property but they already exists then you have the error...

You shoud find a way to that var entity = await GetEntityByIdAsync(input.Id); with an include.
So you override the method add an include, and it should work.

We keep in touch ;)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you have a custom property with:

- `JsonElementId` != 0, **AND**
- an [entity state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitystate?view=efcore-2.1) = `Added` (probably)

I don't know how this occur.

But `JsonElementId` is probably configured as `IDENTITY`. That is his value is calculated by the db. So if you provide a value to the db, the db complains, except if you `SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF` that is if you ask the db the authorization to set the value (not recommended here).

So you have to found why your CustomProperty:

- is not in an `Unchanged` state, or
- get a non 0 key.